# Problems in calling module function in Python?

Tags: python

I have a `segmenting.py` module in a package called `processing`.

I am trying to call a function in the module in my main. It is extremely simple.

**In `main.py`**

```
from processing import segmenting

segmenting.test()
```

**In `segmenting.py`**

```
def test():
    print 'succeed'
```

However, I end up with errors as follows:

```
>>> from processing import segmenting
>>> 
>>> segmenting.test()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
>>>
```

**Where went wrong?**

Comment: Do you have a __init__.py in your package?

Comment: Note that stackoverflow cut the "_" before the init and after. There are 2 underscores before and after.

Comment: @BenMezger without `__init__.py` the import wouldn't work

Comment: your code works perfectly for me (obviously, adding `__init__.py` you do not mention to the package)

Comment: @BenMezger: use backticks: `__init__.py`.  See http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code

Comment: `__init__.py` is likely not the issue, as the `from processing import segmenting` line executes without error.

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins  exactly, I have my init file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you didn't restart your interactive interpreter after editing (and saving!) `segmenting.py`.  Modules are imported only once and cached.  If you edit the source code and then run the `import` statement again, the module is simply retrieved from the cache and doesn't pick up your changes.  See also the [`reload()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload).

Comment: But Python is also OOP like Java right? I don't have to "construct the object and then run its method?" Just directly call the functions in a .py file will do?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to OOP.  No classes involved here, at least not in a way that would matter in the given context.

Comment: So under what circumstances do we construct an object out of a class in Python? It seems that I have been using python to write __scripts__